# C# How to affect Chase Payment Tech Orbital recurring execution time

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, win64

I feel like I'm about to take a dive off a cliff on this one so please be kind :)
I have a small application that allows an end user to make credit/debit/ach auto payments over the phone in a call center type of environment.  One requirement was to allow for setting up future payments using any payment method.  So to do this I create a profile using the Orbital api and then setup a recurring schedule to execute the payment.  I then setup a post dated payment in the loan servicing system.  All of this works beautifully.  The problem we are running into is that the scheduler for Orbital is on the east coast and as such, if a customer makes such a payment and is say on the west coast or Pacific Standard Time, the money gets authed and captured up to 3 hours early.  The question, does anyone have any ideas on how to affect the scheduler in Orbital on a per transaction basis.  So for instance, if the customer is in California it executes say at 3am which would be at 12am PST.  If the customer is on the east coast it executes at its regular 12am.  One thought I had was to take the date of the payment check their timezone and add a day to it if they aren't eastern standard time to make sure the money isn't captured early. Is that my best bet (seems kludgy to me)? I really have this nagging feeling I'm missing something easy. Hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say timezone conversion is your best bet.But don't add a day. Add a time appropriate to the timezone.
For instance in your case the conversion is from PST to EST. You would want to add 3 hours to all the transactions that are being made from the west coast.